# Change the proxy settings in Safari?

Tags: macos, proxy, safari, vpn

It is required to change the proxy server settings in the Safari browser by standard means.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Safari uses the System Proxy Settings.

You can change those using System Preferences -> Network.

If you need to change the Proxy Settings using the command-line, there is a tool called `networksetup` on macOS. With options to configure proxy settings
`networksetup [-setwebproxy networkservice domain portnumber authenticated username password]`.

If you need more control, macOS stores proxy settings in the System Configuration store, which you can manipulate using the `scutil` command-line tool or using the API's in the [SystemConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration) Framework.

Comment: I tried to do this, but in the end, not all sites open, and the site https://2ip.ru does not display these changes, but in the settings, however, you can see it ... Why did everything happen this way?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you've changed and what didn't work?